# Second derivative of $2^{\sqrt{-6x^2-|x|+1}}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I find it insanely hard to calculate the second derivative of $$f(x)=2^{\sqrt{-6x^2-|x|+1}},$$ and my result doesn't even agree with WolframAlpha. Could you show me step by step how to do this computation and then how to study when it is positive?

Comment: to make your life easier start by taking $\log_2$

Answer (score 0):

### Hint:

$$|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$$

$$\frac{d}{dx}[a^{f(x)}]=a^{f(x)}*f'(x)*\log(a)$$

Answer (score 0):

Try following up from what I've done; should be helpful as a hint.

[image]